# 2 way server-client UDP in java

Tags: java, sockets, udp, port

I want to write a program in java that handles two way communication between server and client using udp.Most of the sources online specify only one way,that is from client to server.I want the server to be able to send messages to the client as well.

Comment: Really? So the client can't even tell if the server got the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot use TCP, you can still achieve the same behaviour with UDP.

There are three aspects to consider.

First, that you mentioned: you want to communicate both ways. You can do that by running a sender and a listener thread on both the client and the server.

Second: UDP packets are not guaranteed to arrive. You have to implement an ACK logic in your application layer.

Third: UDP packets are not guaranteed to arrive in order. You have to implement some kind of ordering in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a connection-less protocol on top of IP. This just means that there is no established connection you receive on the other end, you just receive packets of data. To answer back, you have to send a packet "back" to the client.

For this the client needs to be reachable however. This might or might not work through firewalls. Usually firewalls get "punched through" if the client initiates the conversation, but there is no guarantee.

Note also, that UDP packets may arrive out of order, duplicated or not at all. You have to be ready for all. If you send bigger (than MTU) packets, they may have a higher chance of not arriving due to splitting.

Comment: UDP packets will arrive entire or not at all. Never chunked.

Comment: You're right, even if it's split on the network, reassembly is transparently handled. Corrected.